# Need a POPUP thickbox for fileupload in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, popup

**strong text** Hi pals,

I need a Thickbox or any other category of POPUP structure to Upload files to
server using same and close successfully after work. If any body have good code
give me ...

regards
Anes

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/demo/) for the uploader

Some of the features that I have found most helpful are:

> The user can upload all the files at once using ctrl + clicking on all of
>   the files
>
> As the files are being downloaded a queue is displayed which
>   shows the files being downloaded including a completeion bar.
>
> As files are completed they are removed from the queue
>
> It also allows you to specify which file types the user is
>   able to download (they can only see the ones you choose)